# Update database from Android Studio application

Tags: java, php, android, database, sql-update

I've made an Android Studio application that presents data from a database on the website and can register new users in the application. However I want to also be able to update the users that are already in the database. The database is held online with 000webhost, as it needs to be accessible from multiple machines, so MySQLite won't be of any use to me. Does anybody know how I can update data in the five fields of my online database directly through the application I have built? Thanks in advance.

Comment: wait why dont you write API on php and just send requests for select/updating from android app?

Comment: Hi @DEADMC, could you tell me how to do this, or link me to a tutorial? I'm not good with PHP at all as I'm still only in the learning process and don't really know what you're telling me to do, thanks for the reply

Comment: https://www.leaseweb.com/labs/2015/10/creating-a-simple-rest-api-in-php/ for example